# does smtp server send MX query every time it sends an email to same domain

Tags: email, dns, smtp

Does smtp server send MX query every time it sends an email to same domain.

Does smtp server cache any mail-server address?

I know that Dns server does caching , however i was curious to know whether each time we send email to same person,does mail server does MX query to DNS server or it has some pool of addresses for commonly used mail-server(Ex:if i have many friends using gmail and i am regularly sending mails to gmail.com)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK SMTP servers do almost no caching of DNS replies.
It makes very little difference if [caching DNS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server#Caching_name_server) is located on the same server or LAN.  It is highly recommended for any serious SMTP server.

Comment: thnx for replying,but if it caches dns replies to improve efficency as there is no local caching dns server in same network,what is the problem of caching dns replies?

Comment: It is a needles complication.  It seems that implementing DNS caching in SMTP server would not be "cost effective" with "use local caching name server" as an easily available alternative.

Comment: well said ,One more Question,,,,I came through a article which says DNS caching is done by O.S(Windows).,so do you think that smtp server (In Windows) can read addresses from O.S. DNS Cache rather than approaching for caching DNS server (Using Mx record).